# Forge Server-Cannot Assign Requested Address

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-forge

I got my Forge server ready. My IP and everything, but it has this error:

```
[17:51:01] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: Holder lookups applied
[17:51:01] [Server thread/INFO] [net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer]:  Loading properties
[17:51:01] [Server thread/INFO] [net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer]:   Default game type: SURVIVAL
[17:51:01] [Server thread/INFO] [net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer]:  Generating keypair
[17:51:02] [Server thread/INFO] [net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer]:  Starting Minecraft server on 192.***.***.***:25565
[17:51:02] [Server thread/WARN] [net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer]:  **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
[17:51:02] [Server thread/WARN] [net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer]:   The exception was: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
[17:51:02] [Server thread/WARN] [net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer]:  Perhaps a server is already running on that port?
```

[image: Error]

I went to the CMD too and where should I get my IP from? I got mine from under my Default Gateway under Wireless LAN. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like it says the error on the last line where it says, `Perhaps a server is already running on that Port?`.

Comment: Default gateway would be the IP of your router, not your PC.